# Proof : If $f$ continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$ and there is $c \in (a,b)$ so $(f(c)-f(a))(f(b)-f(c))<0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I need to proof this :

If $f$ continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$ and there is $c \in (a,b)$ so $(f(c)-f(a))(f(b)-f(c))<0$ then there is $d \in (a,b)$ so $f'(d)=0$.

I'm not sure If I proof it correctly because is seems too easy, I'll be glad to receive feedback.

Since: $$(f(c)-f(a))(f(b)-f(c))<0$$

We can conclude using the Intermediate Value Theorem that there is $d \in (a,b)$ so $f(d)=0$, and is clear that for the same $d \in (a,b)$ we chose $f'(d)=0$ Since the derivative of zero is zero.

Conclusion : we found $d \in (a,b)$ so $f'(d)=0$.

I wonder if my proof is correct, will be glad to receive feedbacks.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In the expression $f(d) = 0$, both sides are constants, so taking the derivative yields $0 = 0$. It is false, in general, that if $f$ vanishes somewhere then so does $f'$; consider $f(x) = x$ at the origin.

Comment: @Unit Oh, I see what you mean, didn't thought of that actually Thanks:)! I'm struggling with this problem can you help me with it?

Comment: The existence of a point $c$ such that $[f(c)-f(a)][f(b)-f(c)] < 0$ tells us a lot. For one, $xy < 0$ is a compact way of writing "$x$ and $y$ have opposite signs". Unraveling what this means for $f$, we see that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are either both bigger than $f(c)$ or littler than $f(c)$. Now draw a plot of $f$ with horizontal lines through $(a, f(a))$ and $(b, f(b))$. One of these lines will cut the curve $(x, f(x))$ somewhere; now use MVT!

Comment: @Unit Thanks for your help, I have a question instand of using the MVT, Can I say that since that is $c \in (a,b)$ so $f(a)>f(c)$ and $f(b)>f(c)$ (or vice versa), we can conclude since we know that $f$ cannot be monotonic increasing/decreasing, that there must be two point $x,y \in (a,b)$ so $f(x)=f(y)$ then use Rolle's Theorem?

Comment: Exactly! You can even be more concrete: if $f(c) < f(a) < f(b)$ then take $x = a$ and $y \in (c, b)$ (by IVT). In any case, Rolle's Theorem is the way to go (do note, however, that it is equivalent to the MVT).

Comment: All clear!, Thank you for you'r explanation! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = x^2 + 1$. It is continuous and differentiable on $[-1, 1]$, and has no $0$ on this interval. Moreover, we have that 
$$(f(0) - f(-1))(f(1) - f(0)) = (1-2)(2-1) = -1 < 0$$
so this satisfies all the assumptions of the question with $a = -1, b=1$, and $c=0$. However, $f(x) \ne 0 $ for all $x\in [-1, 1]$, so that's an example of why your proof doesn't work.

For a hint about one way to go, you might note that if $(f(c) - f(a))(f(b) - f(c))< 0$, then one of the terms is negative while the other must be positive, and go from there.

Comment: @JaVaPG: Also, draw the picture. In one case $f$ is higher at $c$ than at $a$ and $b$. Do you know any theorem whose conclusion is the existence of a zero-gradient point? Then your goal now is to find objects satisfying the conditions of that theorem.

Answer (score 0):

"and is clear that for the same d∈(a,b) we chose f′(d)=0" is incorrect. It is not sufficient to deduce that $f^{\prime}(d)=0$ from $f(d)=0$.  Suppose $f(x)=x$, then $f(0)=0$, but $f^{\prime}(0)=1$.

Comment: If $f'(x) = 0$ then how can $f'(0) = 1$?

Comment: sorry for typos